# Packaging PCB and battery inside enclosure - foam

Tags: batteries, pcb, enclosure

What's the name/type of the dense foam that's generally used in consumer electronics to stop components from vibrating around and tightly packaging everything together? In my case, this would be for mounting the battery against the back of the PCB and keeping the battery from moving around inside the enclosure. Been searching the traditional electronics part sellers and couldn't find anything suitable.

PS: Would prefer not to use sticky tape as the battery is supposed to be removable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many kinds of foam and foam tapes. I suggest a foam tape stuck to the enclosure or the PCB. [Here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/3M%20PDFs/40xx%20Series%20Datasheet.pdf) is just one of many, many types (a urethane foam). Other plastic foams such as polyethylene, vinyl and acrylic are available (and more exotic materials such as polyimide foams).

It's up to you to evaluate the suitability of the material and the adhesive and the physical characteristics like thickness and so on for your application.

You'd want to consider flammability and working temperature range as less obvious characteristics.